# Is there a way in JHDF5 (HDF5 for Java) to list all paths in a HDF5 file?

Tags: keras, hdf5

Is/are there any method(s) in JHDF5 (HDF5 for Java), which can be used to list all the paths in an H5 file?

I have an H5 file, (generated using Keras) and I have no idea how to retrieve the dataset from it. No matter how hard I look, I am not able to find a method which can do this. Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create an `HDF5ArchiverFactory` and `open()` (or `openForReading()`) your file.  This gives you a `IHDF5Archiver` (or `IHDF5ArchiveReader`), on which you can call `list()` to get the members of the archive.

The documentation for JHDF5 is horrific auto-generated nonsense.  It might be worthwhile to find a more high-level library if your needs are not too complex.

Comment: This helps a lot!! As you mentioned, JHDF5 documentation is very poor. I am trying to read a dataset (it is a sparse matrix) from this file. I will try to work with JHDF5 for a bit before I try something else. Thanks a lot for the help!